# How do you use an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a project at school due, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have to ask the user to how many numbers they would like to enter, and to enter in each number. Then I have to display each number. Can someone tell me when I'm doing wrong?
My code so far:

```
public class Array_practice {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);     
    System.out.println("How many numbers would you like to enter?");
    int a = input.nextInt();
    int b = a;

    int[] num = new int[b];
    int s = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter number " + s + " : ");
        num[i] = input.nextInt();
        s++;
    }

    System.out.println("---------------------");

System.out.println("You entered: ");
for(int x = 0; x <= a; x++)
{
    System.out.println(num[x]);

}
}

}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you compiled and run this code?  Please post the description of your problem, including any errors, exceptions, or incorrect output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int x = 0; x <= a; x++)
{
    System.out.println(num[x]);
}
```

should be

```
for(int x = 0; x < a; x++)
{
    System.out.println(num[x]);
}
```

or you will have ArrayOutOfBoundException, because first element of array is 0, and last is length-1

Comment: right but it's also safer to use `num.length` instead of `a`